# Bootstrap medium screen layout error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make this layout for a medium screen, where the black box is my container, and the red/blue boxes are in two different divs as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul>
        <li>
             image
        </li>
        <li>
             image
        </li>
        <li>
             image
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul>
        <li>
             image
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
             image
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

So the large screen works well, the mediums screen however does not work well, I want the first div to take the primary role and still display as 3 images in a row.

Comment: this is happening because the `col-` are floated in bootstrap....if you want to change it, add a media query for you medium screen size or try removing `float` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the twitter bootstrap documentation which can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you will notice that there are CSS classes for specifying different columns for different device sizes.

[image: Bootstrap column sizes]

Using the information provided here you should be able to add the appropriate classes to your layout so that the layout will respond to the device size the way you want it to.

**EDIT:**

Remove the `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s and replace them with this instead:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...Image...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...Image...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...Image...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`, but for some reason I am still getting the right hand div stacking on top of each other. Any idea what I should be doing number wise?

Comment: You need to remember that the bootstrap grid operates on 12 columns. So all of the columns that are visible on the specified resolution need to add up to 12. The reason it's still stacking is because you have gone over 12.

Comment: okay, I may have skimmed over your code too quickly. I have updated my answer. I didn't realise you were using `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s for the columns.

Comment: thanks, surely it's ok to use the `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s inside the div though as I may need to change their behaviour etc individually in the future

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. Not for the way you're using it anyway. If this has answered your question please mark it as the correct answer. Otherwise, happy to have helped :)